# How can I use Vuex in Sweetalert2 modal?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, sweetalert2

I'm using sweetalert2 with a vue component injected in the html template of modal. How can I access the vuex inside my component?

```js
        Vue.prototype.$myComponentDialog  = function (title, propsData) {
            let swalOptions = {
                title: title,
                showCloseButton: true,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                html:
                    '<div id="component-container"></div>',
                onBeforeOpen: () => {
                    let ComponentClass = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
                    
                    let instance = new ComponentClass({
                        propsData: propsData
                    });
                    instance.$mount();
                    document.getElementById('component-container').appendChild(instance.$el);
                }
            };
            return Vue.swal.mixin({
                customClass: {
                    container: cssClass
                },
                position: 'center'
            }).fire(swalOptions);
        };
```